# How to make child of a daemon process interactive in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I want to spawn an interactive process from a daemon. How can I achieve that? I have tried following code snippet:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (fork()) exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    freopen("/dev/null","w",stderr) ;
    freopen("/dev/null","r",stdin) ;
    freopen("/dev/null","w",stdout) ;
    /*
     */
    if (fork()) exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    pid_t shell_pgrp = getpgrp () ;
    pid_t my_pid = getpid () ;
    int shell_tty = isatty (fileno(stderr)) ?
        dup (fileno(stderr)) : open (ctermid(NULL), O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) ;
    shell_tty = fcntl (shell_tty,F_DUPFD,10) ;
    fcntl (shell_tty,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC) ;
    if (shell_tty < 0) exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    if ((shell_pgrp = tcgetpgrp (shell_tty)) != getpgrp()) {
        setpgid (my_pid,shell_pgrp) ;
    }
    if (shell_pgrp < 0) exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    if ((shell_pgrp = tcgetpgrp (shell_tty)) == getpgrp()) {
        signal (SIGTTIN,SIG_IGN) ;
        signal (SIGTTOU,SIG_IGN) ;
        signal (SIGTSTP,SIG_IGN) ;
        signal (SIGHUP ,SIG_IGN) ;
        signal (SIGQUIT,SIG_IGN) ;
        signal (SIGQUIT,SIG_IGN) ;
        if (!tcsetpgrp (shell_tty,shell_pgrp)) {
            argv++ ;
            if (execv(argv[0],argv) < 0) {
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did your code snipped work or not?

Comment: No it's not. If I run it to spawn a non-interactive process, I do not get control to the terminal.

Comment: What do you mean by 'interactive'?  Your code above tries to open the controlling terminal, but a process spawned from a daemon won't have a controlling terminal.  There is no 'the terminal' for it to get to control.  What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this my self, but i do not think duplicating the standard file
descriptors will work. I believe your spawned process need to acquire a new controlling terminal. [This](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl) API will probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

As having something in the background suddenly take over the terminal can be disconcerting to the user, how about launching an xterm using the command line option to have it launch the desired process?

(Obviously this only works on a system with X or another GUI)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring SIGTTIN and friends does not remove the underlying problem that caused them to be generated in the first place.

I imagine in your example writing output to the terminal works fine, but reading either gets nothing or partial data.  This is because your program reading data from the terminal doesn't stop someone else reading data as well.  When the terminal is your shell, this leads to situations where you need to double every character to try and recover from whatever problem you had which caused this.

Yes, you can run a program from the command line which will stop it from reading data and allow your other program to come in and grab the input but…if you can arrange for that, you should just arrange to have the program which is running do the user interaction itself and send the results to the daemon/child-of-daemon via IPC.